# Baffling inability to auth with requests: NoneType error

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, nonetype

I am not seeing anyone else have this problem, and it just seems to have cropped up for me. So how do I determine if this is a local install problem or (and I *highly* doubt this) an issue with the library?

Using `requests`, I have been running the basic authentication for a while without an issue. But today I am finding I can't authenticate at all.

So if I:

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
s.auth('username', 'pass')
```

I immediately get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-1e7d22bf85ad> in <module>()
----> 1 s.auth('user', 'pass')

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Doesn't matter if I spin up a new virtual environment and fresh install `requests`. This has never been an issue before and suddenly it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

s.auth is an attribute and not a method, so you cannot call it. 
        s.auth = ('username', 'pass') 
is the assignment you want to use.

Comment: gah! i suppose it's time to go to bed.

Comment: This got me too. Thank Goodness for Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the call you are looking to make and tell the session what source you would like it to apply the auth to after instantiating the session

something like:

```
>>> s.get("http://example.com", auth = ('user', 'pass'))
<Response [200]>
```